# Move a folder recursively to another folder with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell

I've tried to search but didn't find, how would I move a folder in a document library to another folder in the same document library recursively?

What I know, I know the name of the folder which I want to move and I want the name of the folder to which I want to move, but all of this should happen recursively, as the folder which has to be moved contain subfolders and files.

Now there are multiple folders to move 100+, and i just need to know how i can do it for one, then i can do it in a loop for 100+

Maybe anyone has an example powershell script or give me the directions?

Comment: You can map the library to external drive & just do cut-paste.

Comment: that is correct, but i have multiple folders, just for example i would like to know how to move one, if i can do that i can move 100.

Comment: Just check my answer below. I will update it with steps.

Comment: Your target document library is in same site collection or different? Are there any meta data involved? Are there any checked out documents as well to move?

Comment: Hey Shkipper, Is the link which I provided you in comment works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The old ‘Open Library in Explorer View’ option in SharePoint may get
>   you out of trouble if the directory structure and number of files is
>   fairly small. Simply use the Explorer View to open the SharePoint
>   library up in a Windows Explorer window and then copy/paste or
>   drag/drop into the Window and the magic will start to happen.

If you want to move folder structure to/from same library than you should check at least below article as there are many ways to do the same but the **only option 5** can help you in your case.

[How to bulk upload/copy a folder structure and files to SharePoint](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/how-to-bulk-uploadcopy-a-folder-structure-and-files-to-sharepoint/)

To map your library as network drive, Kindly follow the steps mentioned in below article.

[Using SharePoint Document Library as a Network Drive](http://mroffice365.com/2012/02/using-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/)

Comment: How does this help me? I still need the script to copy folders recursive to another folder, and i'm talking about 100+ . I'm not going to do it manually...

Comment: If you strongly insist for powershell script than please try this...http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/move-files-between-document-libraries-with-metdata-version-history.html

Comment: You should use same library as a destination with its folder name.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Did it helped you?